# Core Plot x axis values scale and adding a button

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I have a problem. I need to change the x axis value scale. Right now is 0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0... I want it to be 0, 1, 2, 3...
How do I accomplish this? The code I'm using looks like this:

```
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];
CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = (CPTGraphHostingView*)self.view;
hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;
graph.paddingTop = 20;
graph.paddingRight = 20;
graph.paddingLeft = 20;
graph.paddingBottom = 50;

CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace*)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromString(@"-0.5") length:CPTDecimalFromString(@"5")];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromString(@"-2.5") length:CPTDecimalFromString(@"5")];
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;


CPTScatterPlot *mainPlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:graph.bounds] autorelease];
CPTMutableLineStyle *line = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init];
[line setLineColor:[CPTColor blueColor]];
[line setLineWidth:1.5f];
mainPlot.identifier = @"Main Plot";
[mainPlot setDataLineStyle:line];
mainPlot.dataSource = self;
[graph addPlot:mainPlot];
[line release];
```

And I also have to add a button to the bottom of the view. I pulled out a button in IB and connected it to my outlet. I tried bringing it in front by using `[hostingView.superview bringSubviewToFront:backButton];` but I didn't have any luck. How do I accomplish this?

EDIT:
I managed to bring that button to the front by using `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:backButton];` but it mirrored the button around the middle of the view. Not sure how is this even possible? How do it fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several axis labeling policies available in Core Plot. There is a demo in the Plot Gallery example app that shows all of the available policies.

You shouldn't add any subviews to the graph hosting view. Instead, add both the hosting view and button as subviews of another view.

Comment: Can you show me how do I add a `CPTHostingView` as a subview to my main view? I tried `[self.view addSubview:hostingView];` but it didn't work out the way I hoped it would :)

Comment: I fixed the problem. I didn't alloc-init the hosting view. Its working now. Thanks.